# Posting MVC Razor form from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

Within a Partial View, there is a form(@addName) using Html.Helper classes (TextBoxFor, DropDownListFor, etc).

```
@model Models.ADP

using (@Html.BeginForm(new { id= @addName}))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndValue, new { id = @newName, size = "5", style = "margin-right: 10px" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ModuleTypeId, new { @Value = @ViewBag.ModuleId }
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DPId, @dpList, "Choose an Option...", new { @class = "select" })
}
```

I intercept the submit in order to post and retrieve new data asynchronously, divId is the div for the whole Partial View.

```
    $('#@saveName').click( function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SaveADP", "Dispense")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#@addName').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $('#@divId').html(data);
            }
        })
    })
```

The SaveADP action is being called, but the only field with a set value is EndValue, the other fields(ModuleTypeId and DPId) have the default values instead of their form values.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How does your action look like?

Comment: `public ActionResult SaveADP(ADP newDP)` is the signature, ADP has the fields StartValue, EndValue, ModifiedDate, DPId, ModuleTypeId, and Duration.  I haven't gone beyond that yet since newDP isn't being constructed with correct values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ASP.NET MVC agnostic way to do it is to give id for each elements and then pass it to the controller as JSON. As its a partial, it would be better suited for your need as the response could be fetched on the callback of the ajax request.

Example

```
var DTO = {
    newDP: {
        StartValue: $("#id_of_elm").val(),
        EndValue: $("#newName").val(),
        Duration: $("#id_of_elm").val(),
        ModuleTypeId: $("#id_of_elm").val(),
        DPId: $("#id_of_elm").val()
    }
};

$('#saveName').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json'
        data: JSON.stringify(DTO),
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("SaveADP", "Dispense")'
    }).done(function (data) {
        $('#divId').html(data);
    });
});
```

Unrelated, but important points

1. Please use `#saveName` instead of `#@saveName` and `#divId` instead of `#@divId`
2. Please note that `jqXHR.done()` is the new way of handling success callback in `$.ajax`

Comment: This seems like the best idea to id the fields since they need to be, thanks!  The razor variable names...lets just say some things are more difficult than they have to be when you can't create new models but need to reuse views :)

Comment: transferring from webforms to mvc is a pain in the ass but this makes it easier thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**First**, `.serialize()` excludes hidden fields.

**Second**, you should check if HTML of your drop-down list fits the following rules for ["successful controls"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2).

There is a quote from [API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

> **Note**: Only "[successful controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2)" are serialized to the string. No
>   submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted
>   using a button. For a form element's value to be included in the
>   serialized string, the element must have a name attribute. Values from
>   checkboxes and radio buttons (inputs of type "radio" or "checkbox")
>   are included only if they are checked. Data from file select elements
>   is not serialized.

**Successful controls**:

> A successful control is "valid" for submission. Every successful
>   control has its control name paired with its current value as part of
>   the submitted form data set. A successful control must be defined
>   within a FORM element and must have a control name.
>
> However:
>
> 1. Controls that are disabled cannot be successful.
> 2. If a form contains more than one submit button, only the activated submit button is successful.
> 3. All "on" checkboxes may be successful.
> 4. For radio buttons that share the same value of the name attribute, only the "on" radio button may be successful.
> 5. For menus, the control name is provided by a SELECT element and values are provided by OPTION elements. Only selected options may be
>      successful. When no options are selected, the control is not
>      successful and neither the name nor any values are submitted to the
>      server when the form is submitted.
> 6. The current value of a file select is a list of one or more file names. Upon submission of the form, the contents of each file are
>      submitted with the rest of the form data. The file contents are
>      packaged according to the form's content type.
> 7. The current value of an object control is determined by the object's  implementation.

Comment: At work we even wrote our custom implementation of `serialize()` to avoid its limitations.

Answer (score 0):

below is the fixed code. I havent tried it but should be working:

```
@model Models.ADP

@using (Html.BeginForm(new { id= addName}))
{
    Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndValue, new {id = newName, size = "5", style = "margin-right: 10px"});
    Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ModuleTypeId, new {@@Value = ViewBag.ModuleId});
    Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DPId, dpList, "Choose an Option...", new {@@class = "select"});
}
```